# 5-way pot pot limit omaha cash game microstakes

Tags: online, cash-game, hand-history, omaha

**Preflop:**

Playing 5 handed. Blinds $0.05/$0.10. UTG limps, cutoff limps. I am on the button with K♣Q♠T⋄9♠ and decide to pot it to $0.55. Everybody calls. Pot is $2.62. Big blind started with 75BB and cutoff with 100BB.

**Flop:**

Flop is T♣4♥5♠. It checks to me and I decide to check it back. I definitely think my hand is too weak to bet. Also there are some reasonable turns that make my hand very strong. So no need to bluff either.

**Turn:**

Turn is 9♥ giving me top two pair and a straight draw. Big blind bets $1.96 and the cutoff calls. What should I do now? Pot is $6.54. Big blind has $5.48 behind. Cutoff has $7.49 behind. I figured there are enough wraps and flush draws or two pairs that I beat. I rarely slowplay sets in a spot like this, so if I am going to raise some hands on the turn, this is probably a good candidate. Of course having QJ or a flush draw on top of the two pair would be much better, but I figured my hand was strong enough with this SPR. On the other hand it was a 5-handed pot. I could be up against a set with a flush draw. In the end I decided to raise all-in. Big blind snapped. Cutoff folded.

**River:**

> River is T♠ giving me the nuts. Big blind shows 9♣9⋄4♣6♣. So I was drawing to a ten or a jack, only 6 outs....

Comment: Nice example situation for low-limits PLO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preflop: eh, not too excited about the hand, but you do have position. If the table has been limping with weak hands consistently, this is OK.

Flop: My first reaction was to agree with checking it back like you did, but the more I think about it, I like a small bet. It's a pretty dry flop and nobody has jumped at the opportunity to bet, so by betting this you could probably narrow the field to 1 or 2 opponents (or perhaps they all fold) and clear up the picture for the turn. If you check, there's a few cards that will improve your hand but also a ton that could get someone else excited, especially when you're talking about 4 people each holding 4 cards. In other words, even though your hand probably isn't a huge favorite, it may be that nobody else realizes the true equity *they* have in the hand against you at this point and they'll fold to a bet.

Turn:  As played, I agree with the raise. You're ahead of everything but a set and the fact you have a T and a 9 help block that.  If you are ahead, there's no point in just calling--you have to raise to charge draws that are behind you.  If you are behind, you do have a few outs.  A couple downfalls from just calling would be either losing value from hands that were behind you on the turn or that you end up losing more on the river from hands that are ahead of you or that outdraw you (since the pot is getting big enough that the river will be hard to fold in a lot of cases), in which case you might as well have raised the turn anyway.

River:  Nice

Comment: I really like your answer here. I mainly play PLO and completely agree with your thought process here. I feel the starting hand is fairly middling at best, leaning a bit on the weaker side (as you mentioned the opponents hand, that is also super weak). Just an addition to the flop analysis here. I agree with betting out here exactly because your hand is rather weak, by leading out you're defining your hand as stronger than it is, middle set, or two pair like 5,4. Thinning the field as Dr.DrfbagIII said is key in PLO. You may even take it down. I think you would have in this case too.